# Torque for front caliper bolt.

Tags: fork

What's the recommended torque of the front caliper bolt for a carbon fork?  The Fork is from a Felt F1. I don't want to damage the fork from over thightening.

Comment: Have you asked Felt?

Comment: I did and they told me to look at my owner's manual. I just wasn't sure so I thought I would ask. The manual "says" 8Nm and not to exceed 10 Nm.

Comment: I read the other answer to my question, but It is an answer for a fork with an alloy steerer, not a full carbon fork. That's why I asked.

Comment: that number certainly sounds reasonable to me (I have a carbon bike myself but have never messed around with the fork). But the first tool I bought having got the bike was a torque wrench!

Answer (score 2):

This is normally specified by the brake manufacturer, not the fork manufacturer. A summarizing table of common torque values provided by Park Tool is [here](http://www.parktool.com/uploads/files/blog/torque.pdf).

For Shimano, they recommend 70-85 inch-pounds, 90 inch pounds for Campagnolo and 68-72 inch pounds for Cane Creek.

However, it wouldn't hurt to check with the fork manufacturer and the brake manufacturer's documentation.

Comment: 1 pound inch = 0.112 984 829 33 newton meter (if anyone is interested!)